# SSRS Using “Jump to Report” expression for Drill through to ignore subtotal in matrix

Tags: reporting-services, matrix

I have a drill through link on the value cell of a matrix to show a detailed report. However when I run the report, users are able to drill through using the sub total of this value. How do I disable the click through navigation for the subtotal only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the “Jump to report” expression (on the Navigation tab, in properties of the cell), return False when in the subtotal.

For example assume one row group and one column group called matrix1_Row1 and matrix1_Col1 respectively and “ReportName” is the name of the report we want to drill to.

Use the inscope function to check that you are not in a subtotal. i.e if both Row1 and Col1 are inscope then this cant be a subtotal.

```
=iif(inscope("matrix1_Row1") AND inscope("matrix1_Col1"),"ReportName",false)
```